# Parse JavaScript-like syntax to my own Java Methods

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, function

Basically I want to be able to do be able to parse a JavaScript-like syntax. For example:

```
var results = system.function('example');  

if(results == "hello") {  
   console_print("ding dong.");  
}
```

So basically you get it, results will be a "string" and `system.function` will call a Java method, and those results will go into the results string.

I want to be able to do basic math, and validation in this as well, but I want this done in Java. Any ideas?

Comment: This will sound silly, but I want to call a JavaScript file (file.js) and run functions from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use JavaScript (not just *JavaScript-like*), and you're using Java 1.6+, then you can use the [Scripting API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/):

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

    String source =
        "var system = new Array();                       \n" +
        "system['foo'] = function(s) { return 'hello'; } \n" +
        "                                                \n" +
        "var results = system.foo('example');            \n" +
        "                                                \n" +
        "if(results == \"hello\") {                      \n" +
        "  print(\"ding dong.\");                        \n" +
        "}                                               \n";

    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.eval(source);
  }
}
```

which will print:

```
ding dong.
```

to the console.

And to invoke Java methods from the scripting language, you could give [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) a try:

```
package test;

import bsh.Interpreter;

public class Main {

  public static void foo(Object param) {
    System.out.println("From Java, param=" + param);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

    Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
    i.eval("a = 3 * 5; test.Main.foo(a);");
  }
}
```

which will print:

```
From Java, param=15
```

The [core interpreter JAR of BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/bsh-core-2.0b4.jar) is only 143 KB: more lightweight than that will be difficult, IMO.

Comment: @Kiers: how did u format that string with `\n`, `"` and `+`? manually or any shortcut?

Comment: @Kowser, I created the JavaScript snippet using a plain text editor and ran it through a JavaScript interpreter. When it ran without any problem, I simply pasted the code inside the empty string literal: `String source = "";` and IntelliJ made sure the quotes were properly escaped and added line-breaks for me.

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted, I want to be able to route it to functions in Java.. or can you do that? If you can show a quick example that'd be fantastic.

Comment: @Mark, you said: _"and system.function will call a function,"_. Perhaps you should edit you question and add this extra information that it's not just a function you want to call, but a Java method.

Comment: That's great, last question. Do you know a way to "Jail" as you could say to the test.Main.foo class, so it could not be re-written to access say test.security.Decrypt, or, test.security.Encrypt?

Comment: @Mark, no, not really. But that sounds like an ideal candidate for a new question here on SO! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) for this. Rhino is an javascript engine that can be embedded in java.

Comment: Is there a more lightweight version of this?

Comment: @Mark, this is the same as my suggestion.